# My question was put on hold, even though I saw someone else ask something similar without it being closed

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, closed-questions

I have a question about my Role-playing Games Stack Exchange post: [How do I test my own game online](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137395/how-do-i-test-my-own-game-online)

I have edited my question now. But why did my question get put on hold, even though someone else asked [a question that was related to it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59808/how-do-i-find-playtesters) (not the same, but related) that wasn't closed?

As you can see, my question was the same type of idea as another question, but a little different. It was put on hold for now. Here’s what I did before: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/137395/2

Comment: Is [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59808/how-do-i-find-playtesters) the related question you're referring to?

Comment: Yes that’s the question

Comment: A link to the version of the question when it was put on hold, before the edits mentioned in this meta: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/137395/2

Answer (score 9):

Questions here don't get put on hold only because they're off topic.  Best as I can tell, you are asking an on topic question.  They can however be put on hold for a variety of other reasons - being too broad, it being unclear what you're asking, and so on.

I've put your question back on hold myself because to me, and from the comments it seems like to other site members, we're not sure what you're asking.

Note how the similar question you link is somewhere around 20x larger than your question.  That's because they take the time to explain what specifically they're trying to do.  (That question also went through some close votes, actually - it initially was very short and just said "where do I find playtesters" and so it started to have the same issue you are having.)

We'd like to help you, but to get good answers you should put a little more into the question. What specifically are you trying to accomplish, what is your situation, and so on.

For example, in this case, if your question is really "I have a dice mechanic and I want to test out its probability," then there will be one kind of answer.  If it's "I have a full RPG rulesystem and I want people to play it online," then it has another kind of answer.  We don't want to guess what your situation is, we'd like you to explain it so we can make good answers.

Just repeating "I want to test online" doesn't make any of us understand what it is you are asking.  Take a minute and explain to us what specifically you're envisioning; what part of the game, what kind of test, what you think a result looks like.

Comment: Does this not seem like a tools-rec question to you?

Comment: It might if he explained more what he was asking. Or it might not.  Remember, e.g. "How do I find playtesters" or "How do I determine probabilities on my dice mechanics" are both valid questions; it's fine for answers to have tools etc. recommended in them as part of answering a more general question.  (Or it might be a dupe of "how do I find online playtesters).  Not enough information to know.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose it is a tools recommending question. It’s simple, where (what forum) can I test my game on

Comment: @JerelLightning ah ok. Well then unfortunately we can't reopen it :(

Comment: @Rubiksmoose so if I asked this question on this discussion/forum like part, would I get answers?

Comment: @JerelLightning if you mean the other websites from my comment, I'm not sure. Certainly no guarantees, but I simply have no experience with them. If you mean [chat], then you *might* get something there, but you'll have to have a mod give you access to write messages there as your rep is a bit too low right now. There's really no part of this site that is forum like though.

Comment: If you mean if you asked it here on Meta, the answer's no.

Comment: Now what you can do is ask a question like https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21411/where-can-i-find-online-playtesters-to-test-encounters-before-presenting-them-to that's not 3.5e focused, if you were willing to provide more info (*is* it 3.5e-based?  Who knows)